# How to convert 71632.0638353154 to 71,632.06 in SQL Server and SYBASE?

Tags: sql-server, database, sybase

Here I have a question about data converting regarding SQL Server and SYBASE.

Take 71632.0638353154 as an example, how to convert it to 71,632.06 in SQL Server and SYBASE?

I know that there is a `convert()` function in SQL Server and SYBASE, but every time when I tried to use it to convert that number, the database UI will throw me an exception.

I use sybase UI to excute below SQL instance:

```
select convert(varchar(30),convert(varchar(8),convert(money,71632.0638353154),1))
```

but this causes this error:

> Insufficient result space for explicit conversion of MONEY value '71,632.06' to a VARCHAR field.

Would anyone tell me how to do it?  thx.

Comment: actually, the sql statement:  select convert(varchar(30),convert(varchar(30),convert(money,71632.0638353154 ),1))  also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to test in Sybase but

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), CAST(71632.0638353154 AS MONEY),1)
```

works for me in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

The more generic solution is:

```
select cast(71632.0638353154 as decimal(10, 2))
```

The cast function is standard SQL and available in most databases.  DECIMAL is a built-in data type.

Comment: That misses the formatting requirement to include commas in the result.

Comment: My apologies . . . I missed the comma.  No ANSI standard way to do that, but the Money method works in SQL Server.

Comment: it works. but seems that it's not in money format. there is no comma